# Android notification on lock screen

Tags: java, android, notifications

Is it possible to show notification on lock screen with API19? It shows in API23 but not in 19. Ive tried to search for a solution but havnt come across any answer i could use.

[API19](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JNgg.jpg)

[image]

[image]

[API23](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jO6b9.jpg)

Comment: That's a feature that depends on the lock screen installed and the user's settings.  Its nothing you can do in your app to change it.

Comment: i see, thanks for the information Game

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Android only officially released lock screen notifications out of the box as of Android 5.0 Lollipop.

There are however 3rd party solutions this such as [NiLS Lock Screen Notifications](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.roymam.android.notificationswidget&hl=en_GB) which is a widget which displays notifications on your lock screen.

Comment: I read something about it in one of the posts, but the assignment im trying to do requires to notify without any 3rd party. I will just have to let them know that its not possible under android running versions under 5.0 from lock screen.
Thanks for the tip though!

Comment: @BadCoder I thought you might have needed a solution without using a third party but unfortunately this just isn't possible. Hopefully you can use different methods to meet your assignment!